# How to do a filter with a queryset result Django

Tags: django

I was wondering if it is possible to filter a queryset result with a queryset object attribute.

Example:

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(name__contains=search)
```

This should return several objects

```
result = Invoice.objects.filter(client_id=clients.id)
```

Now I want all the data inside Invoice that corresponds to the clients.id found.

What is the most optimized way to do it? Since Django is a powerful framework, I was wondering if it has a good and fast way to do it without me having to add the primary result to a list and do a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to extract ID from clients, that will work just fine:

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(name__contains=search)
result = Invoices.objects.filter(client__in=clients)
```

It will result in SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE result.client_id IN (SELECT `id` FROM `client` WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by filtering directly Invoices using lookups

```
result = Invoice.objects.filter(client__name__contains=search)
```

Alternatively, you can find all clients, extract ids, and filter invoices by those id.

```
clients = Client.objects.filter(**your_crazy_search).values_list('id', flat=True).all()
result = Invoices.objects.filter(client_id__in=clients_id)
```

Comment: Second example generates 2 queries for no reason, you can just do that: `Invoices.objects.filter(client__in=Client.objects.filter(**your_crazy_search))`. Django will generate a subquery as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. But in some cases 2 queries is better than 1 query with subquery.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I wanted. I didn't know Django could work with objects like that. Really good to know. Thank you guys!
The query looks a bit weird because I have one field only for either invoice numbers or client name, that's why I have to sort through both.

Comment: Akisame 2> well, sometimes for sure. For most cases however, the db will do a better job of optimizing if it knows what you want outright. But it is a very good point you raise: using an ORM still requires understanding how the db works underneath.